# Regarding setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Tags: android, android-studio

In latest Android Studio we have `content_main.xml` so now we are putting all our widgets in `content_main` which been suggested by Google.

Should I now also use

`setContentView(R.layout.content_main)`

instead of this

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: what is the issue with doing that? do you see something going wrong or suspect something going wrong? Did you try it out and see the difference? If yes, let us know the issue you noticed.

Comment: it's just a filename, use either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should continue using

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and put your widgets in `content_main`

---

Instead of single xml `activity_main`, now you have two xml files generated `activity_main` and `content_main`.

`activity_main` is wrapper and its purpose is to provide Material design widgets and behavior for older Android versions. `activity_main` also includes `content_main`, if you look at it you can find following line

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be all, didn't notice(beginner)..cheers

Answer (score 0):

Its about naming convention.

If you did your activity design in content_main.xml file then use setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

or if you did your design in activity_main then use setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Both will works.